# I cannot send Skype Messages

Tags: skype

I have a problem with my **skype** on my laptop. I can receive messages (not sms) from my friends but I cannot reply them. When I send messages but it shows "pending" .

I uninstalled Skype and downloaded again, deleted all caches and history on Skype Settings but it's still same..

What should i do to solve this problem?

I'm using Windows 8 64 bit.

Comment: Please include OS, and edition information.

Comment: Do you have recently installed YouTube to MP3 converter or similar software on your computer?

Comment: No, I didn't. I was using Skype last night. This problem occured this morning.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an internet related issue.

You could try to perform a `ipconfig /flushdns`,`netsh winsock reset`, and `netsh int ip reset` in a command prompt ran as an administrator.

Also, have you restarted your computer since the issue started to occur? A fresh boot usually fixes most issues.

Comment: Thank you. I did everthing that you wrote but it's still same. I really don't know what happened. I was using Skype very good last night.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem..

Skype Version 11 and Windows 8 doesn't work together. You should delete your files in Program Files(X86)/Skype as well as Appdata/Roming/Skype then uninstall the Skype from Program and Features. Then you should install an older version of Skype (i.e. Skype version 9) .

It works for me and i hope it works for you too..

Comment: Simply deleting files from Program Files is a poor solution and will undoubtedly cause you problems elsewhere.